# What's the point of importing and exporting at the same time in the same typescript file

Tags: javascript, typescript

I read [chart.js](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/master/src/index.ts) source files found lines below:

```
export * from './controllers/index.js';
export * from './core/index.js';
export * from './elements/index.js';
export * from './platform/index.js';
export * from './plugins/index.js';
export * from './scales/index.js';

import * as controllers from './controllers/index.js';
import * as elements from './elements/index.js';
import * as plugins from './plugins/index.js';
import * as scales from './scales/index.js';

export {
  controllers,
  elements,
  plugins,
  scales,
};
```

I understand slightly but not sure enough with the line ***import * as controllers from './controllers/index.js'***; and then export it as a different simple name ***controllers***.

But why ***export * from './controllers/index.js'***;  It seems do duplicate things as import/export the same package.

I search that many ts script is doing like this. Can someone please give some explanation for the benefit/reason of this piece of code?

Won't this cause any dependecy loop issue?

Understand. I saw multiple samples doing this. I thought it based some convention of TS.

Comment: It encapsulates internal directory structure of this library. Whoever uses it then needs to import just one file.

Comment: Why? Giving consumers options on code style probably. Why not ask the developers directly? You won't get a canonical answer any other way

Comment: It's so that you can import controllers directly from chart.js, like this: `import { XController } from 'chart.js'`

Answer (score 1):

They do import/export the same thing, *but in slightly different ways*.

This

```
export * from './controllers/index.js';
```

will re-export all exports from that other file under their original export names. For example, if that file has `export const foo = 'foo';`, that above line will create a named export named `foo`. It allows the use of `controllers` through this file with:

```
import foo from './thepath.js';
console.log(foo);
```

---

But this

```
import * as controllers from './controllers/index.js';
export {
  controllers,
```

instead takes all the imports and puts them into a single named export, a namespace object called `controllers`. It allows the use of `controllers` through this file with:

```
import { controllers } from './thepath.js';
console.log(controllers.foo);
```

---

So it is duplicating exports, but that may well be deliberate so that consumers of the module find it handy to have more options. Such duplication isn't *necessary*, just a design choice they decided to go with.

> Won't this cause any dependency loop?

No, there's no circular dependency.

Comment: _"there's no circular dependency"_... just potential conflicts with the `export *` names